# MemoryError with Discord selfbot during 'bot.run'

Tags: python, out-of-memory, discord, discord.py

Before you tell me, yes I am aware that selfbots can get you banned. My selfbot is for work purposes in a server with me and three others. I'm doing nothing shady or weird over here.

I'm using the following selfbot code: https://github.com/Supersebi3/Selfbot

Upon logging in, being that I'm in about 50 servers, I experience the following:
[image]

This carries on for several minutes, until I eventually get a MemoryError:

```
  File "main.py", line 96, in <module>
    bot.run(token, bot=False)
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 491, in start
    yield from self.connect()
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 448, in connect
    yield from self.ws.poll_event()
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 431, in poll_event
    yield from self.received_message(msg)
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 327, in received_message
    log.debug('WebSocket Event: {}'.format(msg))
MemoryError
```

Can anyone explain to why this is happening and how I can fix it? Is there any way I can skip the chunk processing for the members of every server my selfbot account is in?

Comment: On rewrite at least, you can define your client with `fetch_offline_members=False` in the constructor which means only online members will be loaded. This saves a considerable amount of memory.

Comment: I'd honestly be surprised if your `bot.lastmessage` thing works by the way, all of d.pys classes (at least in rewrite version) use `__slots__` for their classes meaning you can't define arbitrary attributes to it.

Comment: @squaswin `fetch_offline_members` is already being utilized here at https://github.com/Supersebi3/Selfbot/blob/master/main.py unfortunately. Any other ideas?